# Validating form text input as an integer?

Tags: php, validation

I [think?] that all data sent through $_POST is a string. So if I want the user to enter an integer (per my example, I'm asking the user for hours in one box and minutes in another. It wouldn't make sense for them to say 2.5 hours and 22 minutes), how can I validate that?

I do already have a solution which is this:

```
if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hours', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {}
```

Are there any other/better ways of doing this?

is_numeric/is_int fail since the $_POST data is a string. Casting the value may lose data/brings its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good way to determine if the input is a valid integer.

You are correct that every value populated in `$_POST` will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the integer (via Javascript/Jquery/another library) client side prior to sending it to PHP. [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) in PHP is supposed to be for testing if a string variable is .. well, numeric! This is usally the standard way to test a `$_POST/$_GET` variable for numeric values without casting.

Every `$_POST` variable IS a string and without explicitly casting the string you need to an INT, I see your method as being a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a validation library. A sample using [Respect\Validation](http://documentup.com/Respect/Validation):

```
<?php

use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

$isFormValid = v::key('hours', v::int()->between(0,23))
                ->key('minutes', v::int()->between(0,59))
                ->validate($_POST);
```

The `$isFormValid` variable would have `true` or `false` depending on the result.

If you want to do it by yourself, the [int validator from Respect](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/develop/library/Respect/Validation/Rules/Int.php) uses this logic:

```
 is_numeric($input) && (int) $input == $input;
```